# Returning inline defined structure with uninitialised member. C++

Tags: c++, struct, c++17

This questions received too little attention in forums.

It has been asked before but no one captured this little detail. As a result I am not sure if I am doing the right thing:

**Simple example**:

```
struct TEST {
    bool a;
    int b;
};

TEST func() {
    return { false };
}
```

Is this correct? Note that int value is not initialized.
While it would not be a problem to just set it to 0, more problems arise:

```
struct _FILE_MUTEX {
    bool locked;
    HANDLE handle;
};
```

And the last member of the structure could become more and more complex from vector,arrays to function pointers.

Can I leave some of the members empty when returning an inline-initialised structure?

Comment: No problem here. I just need to check if locked is true. Only then I use the handle.

Comment: Also note that `_FILE_MUTEX` is a reserved identifier. Identifiers with leading double underscore or leading underscore + capital letters are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I had no ideea about the leading underscore. I though that if it used in some windows headers it would look good as a writing standard for me.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu Those underscored identifiers are specifically reserved to the implementation (of the standard library, language extensions, operating system headers etc.). If windows used unreserved identifiers, then its declarations could conflict with your (and everybody elses) declarations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called aggregate initialization.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members *and bases (since C++17)* or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members *and bases (since C++17)* are initialized *by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)* by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

Thus, in aggregate initialization you allowed to provide less clauses than members in structure. Every remaining member (e.g. X), that doesn't have default initializer, would be initialized as X{}.